typescript - iteration through fields of typeof union types
I have some fields defined in an interface like so
Interface Fields {
   FieldA: string;
   FieldB: number;
   Common: string;
}

Type GroupA = Pick<Fields, 'Common' | 'FieldA'>

Type GroupB = Pick<Fields, 'Common' | 'FieldB'>

Type GroupType = GroupA | GroupB

Now if I a method that takes GroupType, I can safely iterate through without compilation errors like
function example(group: GroupType) {
   let key: keyof GroupType
   for(key in group){
      const value = group[key]
...
   }
}

The only issue is VS code shows key to be only of type 'Common', shouldn't it show all types available in the union GroupType?
My main question I guess is what is best/safest way to iterate through the union type GroupType?

You can't loop through built time only type info. You can only loop through keys in runtime object. They don't have things to automatically add this array to javascript if you decide to use them in runtime. So only option is looping over Object.keys(group)

@PuiHoLam It's perfectly fine to loop using for (key in group) as OP is doing.

keyof Union produces the intersection of the keys present in the union as described here. Strange that TypeScript safely lets you assign to that key variable.

@RobbyCornelissen Yea but it's looping over keys of the object not keys of Group A|Group B

@RobbyCornelissen key is FieldA or FieldB at runtime, so I'm not sure if what I'm doing here is right or not as there isn't any compilation errors.   Not sure what the best way to iterate through a union type would be.

@GreenRanger You can make a type guard function. function IsObjGroupA(obj: GroupA|GroupB): obj is Group A { return !!obj. FieldA; } if (IsObjGroupA(group)) {...}

• Please [edit] to make your code a [mre] so that we can just copy it into our own IDEs and work on it without having to fix typos (Interface? Type?). • keyof X means that it's a key guaranteed to exist in X, so it's only "Common". You've used an unsafe workaround for ms/TS#3500 (it's a fun read) and it's not clear what exactly the "right" approach is. I'd probably write this code but it depends strongly on your use case. Could you [edit] to show more of a use case?

Sorry about that, I've had to write the question using my phone because logging in to stack overflow is blocked for me at work :(

I'm not sure how to proceed then. Without a [mre] or an [edit] to show the use case I can't really know what you're looking for. Maybe use your work laptop to connect to a wifi hotspot on your phone?

TS tries to find a common type between GroupA and GroupB. In your case, the common type is 'Common', so it infers key as 'Common' only. However, you want key to be either 'FieldA' | 'FieldB' | 'Common' based on the properties in the union type GroupType.
You need to use type guards to refine the type within the loop. Here is a solution to handle this correctly:
interface Fields {
  FieldA: string;
  FieldB: number;
  Common: string;
}

type GroupA = Pick<Fields, 'Common' | 'FieldA'>
type GroupB = Pick<Fields, 'Common' | 'FieldB'>
type GroupType = GroupA | GroupB

function example(group: GroupType) {
  for (const key in group) {
    const value = group[key as keyof GroupType];

    if (key === 'FieldA') {
      console.log(`FieldA: ${value}`); // string
    } else if (key === 'FieldB') {
      console.log(`FieldB: ${value}`); // number
    } else if (key === 'Common') {
      console.log(`Common: ${value}`); // string
    }
  }
}


Won't compile...

@RobbyCornelissen edited full version. Try this
